# Is there something wrong with this min max program?

Tags: c++

You're given a natural number N and a list of N natural numbers. You need to print the smallest and the greatest of the N values in the list, separated by a space character.

**Input**

You'll read from the user number N, followed by N natural numbers.

**Output**

The program will print 2 numbers separated by a space character, representing the smallest and the greatest of the N values, in this order.

Restrictions
0 < N < 50
The elements in the list are integer numbers greater than or equal to -100 and less than or equal to 100.

```cpp
int N, M=0, L=50;
cin >> N;

if(N < 50) {
    for(int R; N >= 1; N--) {
        cin >> R;
        if (L >= R){
            L = L * 0;
            L = L + R;
        }
        if (M <= R){
            M = M * 0;
            M = M + R; 
        }
        R = R * 0;
    }
}
cout << L << " " << M;
```

The program is running but the site i'm running it on isn't giving me all of the point.
Perhaps there's something i forgot about.
Any feedback?

Comment: Why are you doing `L=L*0;
    L=L+R;`?  You can do the same thing using `L = R`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Why `if(N<50){`? Why do you init `M=0,L=50`? You could create some test cases and check the results. A good test case would be: 2 60 70. Expected output: 60 70. Actual output: 50 70

Comment: What made you chose those initial values: `M=0,L=50`

Comment: The incoming numbers are greater than or equal to -100 and less than or equal to 100, so the initial values for `L` and `R` should be 100 and -100, respectively. And as was mentioned in another comment, `L = R` and `M = R` will work just fine. And finally, a minor optimization: you don't need to modify `L` if `L` equals `R`, so the test should be `if (L > R)`; same thing for the test for `M`.

Comment: What about better names, `min` and `max`, for instance? You could (but don't need to) initialise L and R to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, that would allow you to cover much wider range, which wouldn't hurt in any case...

Comment: What should it be ? i changed it to `L=100`, also changed `L/M=R`

Comment: If you want to output just one single character, I'd prefer character literals over strings: `std::cout << ' '`. More a thing of principle, even though character literal is more efficient (but you won't notice anyway).

Comment: BTW, there is fundamental rule of mathematics that says any value multiplied by 0 is zero.  You could replace `M=M*0;` with `M=0;`.  Now applying substitution, since `M` is always zero, `M = (0) + R;` or simply `M = R;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic error when choosing your initial values for min and max. Assume the user inputs '51', '52', '53'. Your code will output '50  53' since `L` starts at 50. You need to choose default values that are on the edge of the possible min/max values. Take a look at this simple edit:

```
int N,M=-100,L=100;
cin>>N;
if(N<50){
    for(int R; N >= 1; N--){
        cin>>R;

        if (L >= R){
            L=L*0;
            L=L+R;
        }
        if (M <= R){
            M=M*0;
            M=M+R;
        }
        R=R*0;
   }
cout<<L<<" "<<M;
```

I should also note that there are unnecessary steps you're taking here such as `M=M*0; M=M+R;` as well, I would suggest renaming variables to more accurately represent what they hold(i.e. int min, max)

```
int total_numbers, max=-100, min=100;
cin>>total_numbers;
if(total_number < 50)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < total_numbers;++i)
    {
        int current_number = 0;
        cin >> current_number;
        if(current_number > max)
            max = current_number;
        if(current_number < min)
            min = current_number;
    }

    cout << min << "\t" << max << endl;
}
```